# jCarouselLite doesn't work when used with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jcarousellite

I am trying to use jCarouselLite for content slider, it works fine without Bootstrap.
I think jQuery must be colliding with Bootstrap.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="jCarouselLite">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="img/aboutus_slider (1).png" alt="" width="195" height="350">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/aboutus_slider (2).png" alt="" width="195" height="350">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite({
        auto: 800,
        speed: 2500,
        visible: 6
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding bootstrap after jquery and/or jquery.ui

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: its bootstrap-min.css, which collides..n i tried palyig like this, but it doesn't results..

Comment: <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: how can i avoid this??any alternative

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem the images seem not fully load. I'm using Bootstrap 3 after some testing it works fine now. Try moving the jCarouselLite adjacent to the jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jcarousellite.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        /* exclusive slide */
        $(".exclusives").jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: ".ex-next",
            btnPrev: ".ex-prev"
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and in your style sheet provide the width and height of the image:

```
.exclusives ul li img {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

Hope this helps